# Saha-Boltzmann Equation

Tags: spectroscopy, plasma-physics, laser-interaction

I am following [Ahmed, Ahmed, Rafiqe & Baig *A comparative study of Cu–Ni Alloy using LIBS, LA-TOF, EDX, and XRF*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/laser-and-particle-beams/article/comparative-study-of-cuni-alloy-using-libs-latof-edx-and-xrf/68D52CC51C7F49BEF0DD757439D4F10D) paper on Laser Induced Breakdown spectroscopy.

It mentions two versions of Saha-Boltzmann equation and I can't understand the difference/similarity in the two equations. One equation is,

> $$
> n_e\frac{C^{z+1}}{C^z}=\frac{\left(2m_ekT\right)^{3/2}}{h^3}\,\frac{2U_{z+1}}{U_z}\,\exp\left[-\frac{E_\text{ion}}{kT}\right]\,\text{cm}^{-3}\tag{6}
> $$
>   Equation 6 gives the ratio of the concentration of two charge states $Z$ and $Z+1$ of the same element ($C^{Z+1}/C^Z$) (Unnikrishnan *et al* 2012; Andrea *et al* 2015), from here we can easily calculate the value of $C^{Z+1}$ by substituting the value of $C^Z$ obtained from Eq. (5).

The other equation is,

> Due to the insufficient number of observed lines in NiII and CuII, it was not possible to draw the Boltzmann plot for the single ionized species, separately. Thus, the Saha-Boltzmann equation was used for estimating the values of $FC^{Ni\,I}$ (or $n^{NiII}$) and $FC^{CuII}$ (or $n^{CiII}$) as below.
>   $$
> \frac{n^{\alpha,z+1}}{n^{\alpha,z}}=\frac{6.04\times10^{21}\left(T_\text{eV}\right)^{3/2}\left(P_{\alpha,z+1}/P_{\alpha,z}\right)\exp\left[-\chi_{\alpha,z}/k_BT\right]}{n_e}\tag{11}
> $$

I tried looking into the mentioned references but that did not help much. Also, I have already calculated if the stated constants are equivalent.

Comment: The factor $2 (2 \ m_{e} \ k_{B})^{3/2} \ h^{-3}$ is roughly $1.084 \times 10^{27}$ to make the equation allow for temperature in units of eV (as in the 2nd example above, i.e., your Equation 11).  Typically the number densities are expressed in units of $cm^{-3}$ which means multiplying my above factor by $10^{-6}$.  If there is a charge state of +6 floating around, the numerical factor goes to roughly $6.505 \times 10^{21}$.  Note that I used double precision and 2014 CODATA values, they may have rounded things or I may be on the wrong track.

Comment: So the temperature factor is separate as the later equation expresses it in eV so that is equivalent to $(k_BT)^{1.5}$. The remaining factors are $2(2m_e)^{1.5}h^{-1.5}$. And when I calculated it, this not equivalent to the given number.

Comment: So it is $h^3$.

Comment: Replace the Boltzmann constant with the fundamental charge to get the conversion to eV, leaving $T^{3/2}$ in place with the understanding that the input temperature will be in eV.